# Install requirements automatically

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I wrote a ruby gem that requires another gem -> 'curl'.

**How can i make it happen that 'curl' my required gem is getting installed along with my own when i run:**

```
gem install MyGem-1.0.0.gem
```

Comment: Why you don't consider [bundler](http://bundler.io/) as a tool?

Comment: seems to be just what i am looking for. why dont u wrap that in an answer?

Comment: Because I didn't think that someone can meet task to write gems before his meet with bundler. It seems to me impossible. =)

Comment: What does your `gemspec` look like? Have you added `curl` as a dependency to it? If so `curl` (and its dependencies) should be automatically installed when you install your gem.

Comment: Bundler is an automation on top of the specification of a gem (or set of gems), not a replacement for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't using bundler, you just need to add 'curl' gem as a runtime dependency in your gemspec file.

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'example', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
```

Detailed reference: http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_runtime_dependency

Comment: Even if you use Bundler you should, otherwise Bundler will not be able to understand that your gem has dependencies. Using Bundler is just an automation on top of the gemspec, not a replacement.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti: That's correct. I just mentioned it in case they thought it's a bundler specific requirement. Anyway, this makes it more clear, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The [RubyGems specifications](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/) (the `.gemspec` file) allows you to list a gem as a [dependency of your gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_runtime_dependency). This will cause RubyGems to install the dependency (in your case `curl`) automatically when your gem is installed.

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  # ...
  spec.add_runtime_dependency 'curl', '~> 1.1'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is good guide for [creating gem with bundler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler)